# PGSQL dump in case of Github Workflow failure

Tags: postgresql, github-actions

I run my tests on Github Workflow, those tests are using a PostgreSQL database as a service.

In case there is a failure of the test suite, I'd like to make a pg dump as an artifact of the build.

The question is simple: how to call pgdump in Github Actions considering PostgreSQL is a service.

Answer (score 0):

It was not that complicated. I added the installation of pg_dump (which I use after my test in case of failure) and the artifact action:

```
    steps:

        -   name: Install pg_dump
            run: sudo apt-get install postgresql-client

        -   name: Run tests
            run: make test
            env:
                DATABASE_URL: postgres://username:password@localhost:5432/database_name

        -   uses: actions/upload-artifact@v2
            with:
                name: my-artifact
                path: var/test-artifact/
```